# What are the proper Adobe After Effects settings for Apple App Store Videos?

Tags: ios, video, app-store, adobe, after-effects

We are submitting a video preview to Apple's App store. The settings are notoriously picky as we have answered an [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069243/creating-an-ios-app-preview-with-imovie/29552521#29552521) on tricks to get these settings right.

We have a new challenge. When starting up Adobe After Effects, one is presented with a series of video choices.

Apple has a helpful summary [here](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-previews/final-cut-pro/Creating-App-Previews-with-Final-Cut-Pro-X.pdf) of the pixel resolution settings for the videos for all the different devices for Final Cut Pro but fails to mention what the right choices are for these questions in Adobe After Effects:

- What is the preset? (NTSC vs PAL vs etc. as seen in the image below)
- Pixel Aspect Ratio (Square pixels or NTSC vs HDV vs anamorphic etc.)?
- Frame Rate (Apple specifies it as "30p." Does that mean 30 fps or 29.97 frames per second with a Drop Frame as is the default in Adobe After Effects)?
- Is Resolution Full (or Half etc.)?

What are the correct choices?

[image: Adobe After Effects Preset Composition Chooser]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the current specifications for the app preview video

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW10